# How to determine which php apache uses?

Tags: php, apache

My phpinfo.php on apache shows

```
PHP Version 5.4.15
```

but commandline

```
php - v
```

shows

```
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38)
```

I think apache and commandline reaches the different php,however

```
which php
```

shows only

```
/usr/bin/php
```

it is 5.4.17

I would like to know where php apache uses, and how can I check which php apache uses?

Comment: In `phpinfo()` there will be info what `php.ini` file is used. There should be path to this file. So for example my: `Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and php should be in `/etc/php5/`

Comment: THanks I found php /usr/local/php5/bin/php I will change the commandline path to this.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that my comment was more for question "Where is my php.ini used by apache" than for your question. If there is linux on server which uses some kind of package system like `dpkg` then probably the easier way would be to ask it where is it storing php like this: `dpkg-query -L php5-common` or `dpkg-query -L libapache2-mod-php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depend on if you run `php` files using `mod_php5` or `cgi`. The difference is explained in the accepted answer in this question: [What is mod_php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712825/what-is-mod-php)

As I understand it, basically `mod_php5` is pre-compiled from a specific `PHP` version that Apache will than use. While if `CGI` is used to run `PHP` the installed `PHP` command line version will be used when spawning a new process each time a `PHP` file is executed.

Hope this helps.