# Enable PHP Apache2

Tags: php, apache

I can find the php5 mod in the mods-available directory, but I'm not sure how to get it into the mods-enabled directory.

Also, I just wanted to check that this is the way to enable php on my device...I know that PHP is installed, but another dev has disabled it (and is uncontactable)!

Comment: Newer versions of apache disable php from inside user folders. Check the end of phpX.conf on mods-enable, comment out the end of it (as it says)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `a2enmod` or `a2dismod` to enable/disable modules by name.

From terminal, run: `sudo a2enmod php5` to enable PHP5 (or some other module), then `sudo service apache2 reload` to reload the Apache2 configuration.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees. This is it.

Comment: For the fools like me that blindly copied the code, use `sudo a2enmod phpX.X` where X.X is the current version of php

Answer (score 79):

If anyone gets

> ERROR: Module phpX.X does not exist!

just install the module for your current php version:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-phpX.X
```

Answer (score 7):

You have two ways to enable it.

First, you can set the absolute path of the php module file in your httpd.conf file like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module /path/to/mods-available/libphp5.so
```

Second, you can link the module file to the mods-enabled directory:

```
ln -s /path/to/mods-available/libphp5.so /path/to/mods-enabled/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `apt-get install libapache2-mod-phpX.X`
2. `sudo a2enmod phpx.x`
3. if there is any other mods conflicts whit it, use this`sudo a2dismod xxx`
4. `sudo service apache2 reload`
5. if you integrate html with php, you must write it in a .php file, rather than .html, or the php text won`t be displayed.
6. by the way, in the folder `/etc/apache2`, you might find something you need