# PHP yii is showing run() in browser. How I can solve it?

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

When I my open my browser for my basic project in yii, browser only show run(), what I need to do? Could you please help me to install yii framework on ubuntu 16.00?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable PHP Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654694/enable-php-apache2)

Answer (score 1):

Methinks your apache2 or nginx configuration is not handling php files correctly. Make sure you have php-fpm or php module for apache2 configured.

Follow answers from this question to accomplish this.
[Enable PHP Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654694/enable-php-apache2)