# API written in PHP on apache web server return the php code itself

Tags: php, apache, api

I have written a simple mock API in apache (httpd, CentOS 7) web server using php. `test.php` which is located in `/var/www/html` is as below.

```
<?php
       $age = '{"Peter":"Good", "Ben":37, "Joe":43}';
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
        sleep(5);
        echo $age;
?>
```

When I call the API (`http://<server_IP>:80/test.php`) in postman, it returns the exact same php code  back.

When I run the php code on the server using `php test.php`, it gets compiled correctly and returns expected output.

```
{"Peter":"Good", "Ben":37, "Joe":43}
```

Why don't I get this output when the API is invoked?
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable PHP Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654694/enable-php-apache2)

Comment: Having the `php` command-line tool available in your shell doesn't mean that Apache will automatically parse files as PHP scripts. They're different tools with different settings and, in Linux, typically different packages as well.

Comment: Then how can I come up with a simple mock API in apache?