# PHPMyAdmin: Blank White page instead of login screen

Tags: phpmyadmin, screen, white-framework

I been having problems with PhpMyadmin:  It returns either code instead of a login screen, or it will just return the blank white page.

Tried the Following (Running Debian 11 - Bullseye on own server.)

PHP:  Version 7.4 installed and both 7.4 and 8.1 available)
MYSQL:Ver 8.0.29 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Apache2 Version 2.4.53
Port 80 and 443 open

I am not sure what plugins or modules I need. I have installed almost everything I can think of, and I get a white blank page, and I know I probably am missing something, but not sure.

Can someone give me a LIST of what I need to install to get this working?  I've done an upgrade from Debian 8.3 to Debian 11, and I am not sure what else I need.

Any Help would be appreciated - This CAN'T be THIS hard :(

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 5):

Use the following to install everything needed. I had the same issue, and I fixed it with the following code:

`apt -y install wget php php-cgi php-mysqli php-pear php-mbstring libapache2-mod-php php-common php-phpseclib php-mysql`

Comment: I am getting error E: Package 'php-mysqli' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your php module is missing/not working in apache2 web server. Try doing steps 1-4 as suggested in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241533

1. `apt-get install libapache2-mod-phpX.X`
2. `sudo a2enmod phpx.x`
3. if there is any other mods conflicts whit it, use this `sudo a2dismod xxx`
4. `sudo service apache2 reload`

Once completed, try reloading the phpmyadmin page again.

Comment: The above response worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue on Ubuntu 22.04

Installing "libapache2-mod-php" and changing 'localhost' to '172.0.0.1' in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php resolved the issue for me.

Answer found [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17737) on github.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; enable one version of PHP, disable the rest.

You have multiple PHP versions installed so what you need to do is enable one and disable all the rest. Then, using your selected PHP version, install the necessary php packages *specific* to your PHP version (say `PHP 8.X`) and restart/reload the server.

1. Check your Apache's **available modules** using `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available` and **enabled modules** using `ls /etc/apache2/modes-enabled` and compare the contents. Check [this screenshot of both commands](https://ibb.co/Tvhkncq) and note the circles. I have both PHP 8.0 and 8.2 installed/available, but only 8.2 enabled.
2. Add `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.
3. For PHP 8.X, install the necessary packages i.e

```
sudo apt install php8.X-cgi php8.X-mysql php8.X-pear php8.X-mbstring php8.X-common libapache2-mod-php8.X
```

4. From your available modules in Step 1, enable the preferred PHP version using `sudo a2enmod php8.X`
5. Disable the rest of the PHP versions using `sudo a2dismod`, e.g

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2dismod php5.6
```

6. Restart/reload your server; `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and/or `sudo systemctl reload apache2`
7. Check Step 1 again, then try accessing phpmyadmin.

**Bonus**
If you'd like to use multiple php versions, install them from [this PPA by Ondrej Sury for Ubuntu users](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) and for Debian users check [this DPA.](https://packages.sury.org/php/)

Comments and feedback are welcome.