# How do I use Fetch in React?

Tags: php, reactjs

```
    React Code:

    const response = await fetch("../componentsunused/testingphp.php", {

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json" // request content type
      }
      
    });
    console.log("myResponse:" + JSON.stringify(response))

    this.setState({ items: await response.json() });

    PHP Code:

    $arr = array('a' => "123");

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

myResponse in console always comes out as an empty array. I checked and the request went through and was returned okay. What is wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: Now I have another problem: the ajax call is returning the entire php file!

Comment: You meaning it is return the content of the PHP file instead of executing and returning the results?

Comment: Yes. I have no idea why. I tried ob_get_clean and everything else but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you started the script with `<?php`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using localhost, and I am going to try this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587684/jquery-ajax-call-returns-entire-php-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241882/discussion-between-ruleboy21-and-yoni-kirby).