# How to let the webserver (e.g. Apache) call Python directly?

Tags: php, python, apache

*(Important) Disclaimer: I know it's probably not a good idea, that Python is not like PHP, and that the "natural" way to do web with Python is more by using a framework like Bottle, Flask, Django (that I already use), etc. But still, just out of curiosity, I'd like to see how the following is possible*.

---

When Apache + PHP are installed, we can access a page like  `http://www.example.com/index.php`. Internally, Apache probably passes the request to PHP which executes code, produces a text output, which is then served by Apache.

**Question: how could we do something similar in Python?** i.e. by accessing `http://www.example.com/index.py`, Apache would call the script `index.py`:

```
print("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>")
```

and then Apache would serve this page to the client.

---

NB:

- Calling `http://www.example.com/index.py?foo=bar` could even give the params to the Python script in `sys.argv`
- I already did it like this: `http://www.example.com/index.php`:

  ```
  <?php 
  $out = shell_exec("python index.py"); 
  echo($out); 
  ?>
  ```

  which then calls the Python script and produces the output. It works, but I'd like to do it without PHP.
- Said in another way, is there something like [`mod_php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712825/what-is-mod-php) for Python?

Comment: apache has module `mod_python` to run python script and also `mod_fcgi` to run script in any language (ie. python, perl, ruby, bash).

Comment: check [Python - CGI programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) to see how to write code for `mod_fcgi`

Comment: Note about bounty (I forgot to add a note): `mod_python` is often cited as non-maintained-anymore. Is there nowadays a good solution that **does not** require a Python framework, and **does not require** a constantly running script listening on a port. Instead, I would just like that when calling www.example.com/test.py, the webserver (apache or nginx) directly calls test.py.

Comment: always has to be some code which runs all time and listening on port. If you run Apache/Nginx/WSCGI then this server runs all time and listening on port. And I wouldn't expect new solution that doesn't require Python framework because frameworks make like easier, and code is better organized. Even in PHP many people prefere PHP frameworks instead of pure PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it thanks to the other answer:

1. Do:

   ```
   apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
   ```
2. Then create or open the `.htaccess` file in your website folder, and add

   ```
   AddHandler mod_python .py
   PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
   ```
3. Then create a file `test.py`:

   ```
   def index(req):
       return("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>")
   ```
4. Now accessing `www.example.com/test.py` works!

---

NB:

- `def index(req)` is really required: using another name will make it fail.
- I don't know why, but it's not possible to set `AddHandler mod_python .py` in a `.htaccess`, I only managed to do it globally for a `<VirtualHost>`. Does someone have an idea about how to do it directly in the `.htaccess`?
- if `mod_python` is already installed but not enabled, you have to do:

  ```
  a2enmod python               
  service apache2 restart
  ```

  but this is done automatically when installing `libapache2-mod-python`.
- This is needed in the Apache `VirtualHost`'s `Directory`: `AllowOverride All`, `Require all granted`, to allow handlers to be added directly *in a `.htaccess`* file. Without it, an alternative is to add the directives `AddHandler ...` directly in the `VirtualHost` definition.

Comment: Note: this works, but `mod_python` is often cited as non-maintained. Is there a newest solution (NB: not requiring any framework nor a constantly running script).

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [similar mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_python) for python, but it's not as widely used and does not seem to have been updated for a few years.

Note: A common way of doing things is using apache/nginx as a web server, and uwsgi as an application server, with the web server redirecting to the application server for non-static content urls.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice and it works (see my other answer)!

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not possible to set `AddHandler mod_python .py` in a `.htaccess`, I only managed to do it globally for a `<VirtualHost>`. Would you have an idea about how to do it directly in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Basj: no, sorry, I just toyed with it a little a few years ago, don't know any details.

Comment: The solution for being able to do it directly in .htaccess @blue_note is: `<VirtualHost> <Directory /> AllowOverride All`...

Answer (score 1):

There is one more module apache can able to server python apart from `mod_python` which is `mod_wsgi` you may have tried it already if not this can be done like below.

First install if not already installed

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi -y
```

Create vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>

    #ServerName www.example.com
    #ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/wsgi>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /var/www/html/wsgi/index.py #path to file

    <Directory /var/www/html/wsgi>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Create index.py

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'<h2>Hello World!</h2>'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make mod_wsgi act like a .py handler? i.e. without of specifying `WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /var/www/html/wsgi/index.py` manually, `www.example.com/test.py` would automatically call `/var/www/html/wsgi/test.py`, `www.example.com/index.py` would automatically call `/var/www/html/wsgi/index.py`, etc.