# AddHandler directly in .htaccess

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, mod-python

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414076/how-to-let-the-webserver-e-g-apache-call-python-directly/58414570#58414570), I installed and enabled `mod_python`.

Why doesn't adding this in `.htaccess`

```
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
```

work?

It works if I add this in a `<VirtualHost>` configuration, but it doesn't seem to work from a `.htaccess`. This is a bit a shame, because some people don't have access to modify their `<VirtualHost>` configuration, and can only modify  a `.htaccess`.

On the other hand, `AddHandler php5-script .php` seems to be available from `.htaccess` as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856825/what-does-htaccess-with-line-addhandler-php5-script-php-do).

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride` set to `All` (or at least `FileInfo`) in your virtual host (or global) configuration?

Comment: @DusanBajic Indeed, adding `AllowOverride All` solved it, as well as `Allow from all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @DusanBajic in a comment, adding this solved it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then simply adding this in the  `.htaccess` file works:

```
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
```

Explanation:

- [`AllowOverride All`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride):

  > When the server finds an .htaccess file (as specified by AccessFileName), it needs to know which directives declared in that file can override earlier configuration directives.